# Proving a sequence's limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm really hung up on this problem. Sorry, I cant use subscripts for my sequences.

> Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{s_n\}$ be sequences. Suppose $L= \lim a_n$ and let $s_n = (a_1+a_2+...+a_n)/n$. Prove that $\lim s_n = L$.
>
> **Hint:** $|s-L| = \left|\frac{(a_1-L)+(a_2-L)+...+(a_n-L)}{n}\right|$.

I Tried proving the $\lim a_n =L$ via

> Let $\epsilon >0$ then there is an $n \ge N=L/\epsilon$ then $|a_n-L| < \epsilon$

But I'm not sure if that will be helpful or where to go from here to show that $\lim s_n =L$. is there something I can say about $s_n$ when $n \ge L/\epsilon$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

The idea would be to say
$$
|s - L|
 = \left| \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n (a_k - L) \right|
 \le \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n |a_k - L|,
$$
and now you can apply that $\delta-\epsilon$ definition and bound the tail of the sum, and since the front part is finite, it will $\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.